# QSortFilterProxyModel filterAcceptsColumn cant set new index data

Tags: c++, qt

im using QSortFilterProxyModel to filter column that im getting from QSqlQueryModel model
but becose the filterAcceptsColumn method is const "all the way"
i have problem to set Qt::UserRole data in the right index . how can i overcome this?

```
    bool MiniSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsColumn(int source_column, const QModelIndex& index) const
    {
        QVariant tmp ;
        if(source_column ==0)
        {

            setRowid(index.data(Qt::DisplayRole)); 
// here im getting compilation error 
//: error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const QString' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
            m_rowId = index.model()->data(index,Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
            return false;
        }
        else if(source_column ==1)
        {
            setYTid(index.data(Qt::DisplayRole)); 
            return false;
        }
        else if(source_column ==2)
        {

            setNewData(index);
            return QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsColumn(source_column,index);
        }
        return false;
    }


    void MiniSortFilterProxyModel::setRowid(QVariant rowId) const 
    {
// here also compilation error:
        m_rowId = rowId.toString();
    }

    void MiniSortFilterProxyModel::setYTid(QVariant ytId) const 
    {
/ here also compilation error:      
m_ytId = ytId.toString();
    }

    void MiniSortFilterProxyModel::setNewData(QModelIndex& index) const 
    {
// here also compilation error:
//error C2511: 'void MiniSortFilterProxyModel::setNewData(QModelIndex &) const' : //overloaded member function not found in 'MiniSortFilterProxyModel'             
 QVariant data = m_rowId+"_"+m_ytId;
            index.model()->setData(index,data,Qt::UserRole);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty fix: declare `m_rowId` as `mutable`

```
mutable QString m_rowId;
```

Anyway, there's a reason if the method was declared const in the Qt API so be sure that one is the only place where you can assign that value.